# LUIS Dispatch Bot sdk V3 support?

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Is it possible to create LUIS Dispatch for existing V3 Bot ? We have v3 bot that's in production and we have gone so far now so its difficult to switch over v4 Bot. However, there are awesome capabilities like LUIS dispatch tool that we would like to leverage.

Ref:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=jsaddref%2Cjsbotconfig#integrate-multiple-luis-apps-and-qna-services-with-the-dispatch-tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that the source code is available for the LUIS components and the provided examples, I think you can use this tool on v3 bot after some modifications.

It looks like the dispatch tool is only preparing a custom LUIS app that you will query from your bot, so nothing really linked to v4 of bot builder.

Comment: As Nicolas said this functionnality is more a time saving feature than a real functionnality. So you can do it on you re own but it is a real time consuming time since you have to copy paste each of your utterances.

Comment: @ThomasR why copy/pasting all the utterances? Can't you still use the tool to generate the generic project?

Comment: To create a dispatch tool you need to create a new LUIS project, each intent in this project will point to a project and each project needs to contain all of the utterances of the project it is pointing at. The generic project tool is not useful in the case you are creating a dispatcher since all the utterances needs to be in the same intent. That's why you need to copy paste and can not use the generic project tool to create an handmade dispatcher.

Comment: @ThomasR, I may have missed something. Where I read the doc I think the dispatch tool (npm botdispatch) is doing the duplication of each LUIS project to the combined one, when you call `dispatch create`. Then in your v3 bot you have to call this combined project

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. You are totally rigth on everything. The dispatchtool merge automatically the projects and just have to call it in v3 bot. I meant that this tool is not a new functionality but a time saving tool which allows to do stuff which was doable before Microsoft Build but spending few hours on it.

Comment: Totally agree yes, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your input. NicolasR and ThomasR. The only link I see for V4 code is accessing QnA . I never accessed QnA in v3 so not sure if I just need to call it manually by request module. For v4 following piece of code comes handy from botbuilder-ai module. 

`const faq = new QnAMaker(
    {
        knowledgeBaseId: 'XXX',
        endpointKey: 'xxxx',
        host: 'xxxx'
    },
    {
        answerBeforeNext: true
    }
);
`

`faq.answer(context);`